# How would I convert UTF-8mb4 to UTF-8?

Tags: java, docx4j, utf8mb4

I'm using docx4j to convert .docx files into html, then saving that data into a MySQL database. Unfortunately, we've hit a snag. When we convert a doc that includes any characters encoded in utf8mb4, and then try and submit that data to our MySQL server, we're hit with a Generic JDBC Exception which states that it doesn't know how to parse the utf8mb4 characters.

ERROR pool-3-thread-20 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBF\xBD???...' for column 'u_content' at row 1

I don't have the 'clearance' to move our MySQL server up to 5.5, so that fix is out.

In Java, can I somehow convert utf-8mb4 back to utf-8 and just convert all utf-8mb4 characters to � or something?

Comment: utf-8mb4 is just MySQL's name for utf-8.  Tell Java it's utf-8 and you're done.

Comment: The docx4j xslt which produces (X)HTML outputs encoding="utf-8"; what are you then doing with the relevant output stream?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?  I found this writeup really helpful: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Comment: markspace, I wish it was that easy. Encoding the exported HTML String data and encoding it as UTF8 doesn't fix the issue. UTF8mb4 support in the MySQL database is still required.
//
JasonPlutext, we're stuffing the HTML data into a MySQL database as a BLOB variable.
//
chrislott, thanks for the writeup. I'll dig through it and see if I can find an answer. :-)

Comment: You could try a 3.3 dev build to see if that works better; it contains improved astral character handling:-  http://www.docx4java.org/forums/announces/docx4j-3-3-0-dev-builds-t2262.html

Answer (score 4):

You should remove bad characters first then persist your content to database.
This will help you:

```
public static String removeBadChars(String s) {
  if (s == null) return null;
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++){ 
    if (Character.isHighSurrogate(s.charAt(i))) continue;
    sb.append(s.charAt(i));
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```